# How to draw on screen rapidly

Tags: c++, graphics, directx

I have a sensor which is able to read color value from the screen very fast (within a few milliseconds). And also I have to change 3 colors, red, green, blue, by rotation within a rectangle (not large) on the screen so fast that rectangle will considered white. My first question: is it possible? Is there any technique allows to fill R,G, and B colors so fast that eye would not be able to determine each separate color, but considered area as a mix? Actually, my monitor refresh rate is 60 Hz, is it enough? 
I implemented it with C++/Qt/Windows 7, but I see only blinking rectangle on my form. It should works with any modern video adapter, even built-in.

Answer (score 0):

The monitor's refresh rate is 60Hz, so the picture is refreshed once every 1/60th of a second or 0.0167 seconds or every 16ms. You didn't specify the sampling rate of the sensor but it sounds like it is significantly faster than your refresh. That means that multiple samples are going to see the same picture.

Comment: How the picture seems for human eyes, white or as separated blinks?

Comment: It will blink as hell burn.